# Browser getting more responsive after a while on heavy web page

Tags: performance, optimization, browser, html

When we load in a very heavy web page with a huge html form and lots of event handler code on it, the page gets very laggy for some time, responding to any user interaction (like changing input values) with a 1-2 second delay.

Interestingly, after a while (depending on the size of the page and code to parse, but around 1-2 minutes) it gets as snappy as it normally is with average size web pages. We tried to use the profiler in the dev tools to see what could be running in the background but nothing surprising is happening.
No network traffic is taking place after the page load, neither is there any blocking code running and HTML parsing is long gone at the time according to the profiler.

My questions are:

- do browsers do any kind of indexing on the DOM in the background to speed up queries of elements?
- any other type of optimization like caching repeated function call results?
- **what causes it to "catch up" after a while?**

Note: it is obvious that our frontend is quite outdated and inefficient but we'd like to squeeze out everything from it before a big rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, modern browsers, namely modern Javascript runtimes performs many optimisations during load and more importantly during page lifecycle: one of them is "Lazy / **Just In Time Compilation**, what in general means that runtime observes demanding or frequently performed patterns and translates them to faster, "closer to metal" format. Often in cost of higher memory consumption. Amusing fact is that such optimisations often makes "seemingly ugly and bad but predictable" code faster than well-thought complex "hand-crafted optimised" one.

But Iʼm not completely sure this is the main cause of phenomenon you are describing. Initial slowness and unresponsiveness is more often caused by battle of network requests, blocking code, HTML and CSS parsing and CPU/GPU rendering, i.e. wire/cache->memory->cpu/gpu loop, which is not that dependant on Javascript optimisations mentioned before.

Further reading:

- http://creativejs.com/2013/06/the-race-for-speed-part-3-javascript-compiler-strategies/
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Comment: Thanks! I should have explained it more thoroughly, the suggestions in your 2nd paragraph are good but most of them are ruled out (edited my question). Is there any way to look into that JIT compilation happening under the hoods? I have a strong suspicion that something like that is causing delays.

Comment: Hm, I think you could "peek under the hood" a bit using Chrome developers tools Timeline [see updated answer] (in case you havenʼt tried it yet). It will tell you **what** causes main jags (if it is really JS, or blocking network request or rendering or constant reflows) but to see actual optimisations, where and how they happen, it is far above my skills and tools. I assume youʼd need to really see actual bytecode in given stages. Maybe some guru around here?